# Tabs not showing content when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

The code works in Fiddle but does not work in Atom. Currently making a chrome extension and I have the following files in a folder I'm using for my extension:

```
Manifest.json

popup.html (this is where my main code is in)

pupup.js (js code in here)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/co6b2chw/5/

Can anyone help me figure out why the extension isn't working?

Comment: It's hard to comment without checking (permissions, content_scripts etc) the manifest.json file, can you share it?